# How do I shift my [ngClass] conditions into a separate ts file as a reusable code across all components, instead of repeating it in every html file?

Tags: angular, typescript, service, ng-class, simplify

Currently I have my codes working. However, my [ngClass] conditions are very bulky. Having it repeated in many components in the html makes it difficult to maintain if any change is needed and makes my code very messy.

Example in my html:

```
 <a type="button" href="#">
        <div [ngClass]="{
           'blue-filter': runTheme==='Blue',
           'green-filter': runTheme==='Green',
           'red-filter': runTheme==='Red',
           'hydrangea-filter': runTheme==='Hydrangea',
           'sakura-filter': runTheme==='Sakura',
           'lavender-filter': runTheme==='Lavender',
           'mediterranean-filter': runTheme==='Mediterranean',
           'industrial-filter': runTheme==='Industrial',
           'minimalist-filter': runTheme==='Minimalist',
           'bohemian-filter': runTheme==='Bohemian',
           'forest-filter': runTheme==='Forest',
           'beach-filter': runTheme==='Beach',
           'sea-filter': runTheme==='Sea',
           'spring-filter': runTheme==='Spring',
           'winter-filter': runTheme==='Winter',
           'summer-filter': runTheme==='Summer',
           'autumn-filter': runTheme==='Autumn'
          }">
          <img src="./assets/iconsTopbar2px/building07.svg" />
        </div>
      </a>

      <a type="button">
        <div [ngClass]="{
           'blue-filter': runTheme==='Blue',
           'green-filter': runTheme==='Green',
           'red-filter': runTheme==='Red',
           'hydrangea-filter': runTheme==='Hydrangea',
           'sakura-filter': runTheme==='Sakura',
           'lavender-filter': runTheme==='Lavender',
           'mediterranean-filter': runTheme==='Mediterranean',
           'industrial-filter': runTheme==='Industrial',
           'minimalist-filter': runTheme==='Minimalist',
           'bohemian-filter': runTheme==='Bohemian',
           'forest-filter': runTheme==='Forest',
           'beach-filter': runTheme==='Beach',
           'sea-filter': runTheme==='Sea',
           'spring-filter': runTheme==='Spring',
           'winter-filter': runTheme==='Winter',
           'summer-filter': runTheme==='Summer',
           'autumn-filter': runTheme==='Autumn'
          }">
          <img src="./assets/iconsTopbar2px/ESS.svg" />
        </div>
      </a>

      <a type="button" routerLink="/login">
        <div [ngClass]="{
           'blue-filter': runTheme==='Blue',
           'green-filter': runTheme==='Green',
           'red-filter': runTheme==='Red',
           'hydrangea-filter': runTheme==='Hydrangea',
           'sakura-filter': runTheme==='Sakura',
           'lavender-filter': runTheme==='Lavender',
           'mediterranean-filter': runTheme==='Mediterranean',
           'industrial-filter': runTheme==='Industrial',
           'minimalist-filter': runTheme==='Minimalist',
           'bohemian-filter': runTheme==='Bohemian',
           'forest-filter': runTheme==='Forest',
           'beach-filter': runTheme==='Beach',
           'sea-filter': runTheme==='Sea',
           'spring-filter': runTheme==='Spring',
           'winter-filter': runTheme==='Winter',
           'summer-filter': runTheme==='Summer',
           'autumn-filter': runTheme==='Autumn'
          }">
          <img src="./assets/iconsTopbar2px/arrowCircleBrokenRight01.svg" />
        </div>
      </a>
```

How to create a single typescript file or a service file to place the conditions inside?

Do note that my runTheme is retrieving its data from a service - ColorSchemeService.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ColorSchemesService } from '../color-schemes.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-top-panel',
  templateUrl: './top-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-panel.component.css']
})


export class TopPanelComponent {
  runTheme: any;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private colorSchemes: ColorSchemesService,
  ) {
    this.colorSchemes.data$.subscribe(data => {
      this.runTheme = data;
    })
  }
```

I am still not sure of how to format my codes properly. Have tried creating a new colorFilter.ts file and link to my component's ts and html, but met with errors.

```
import { ColorSchemesService } from "./color-schemes.service";

export const colorFilter = [
  runTheme: any;

constructor(
  private colorSchemes: ColorSchemesService,
) {
  this.colorSchemes.data$.subscribe(data => {
    this.runTheme = data;
  })
}

  blue-filter04: runTheme === 'Blue',
  green-filter04: runTheme === 'Green',
  red-filter04: runTheme === 'Red',
  hydrangea-filter04: runTheme === 'Hydrangea',
  sakura-filter04: runTheme === 'Sakura',
  lavender-filter04: runTheme === 'Lavender',
  mediterranean-filter04: runTheme === 'Mediterranean',
  industrial-filter04: runTheme === 'Industrial',
  minimalist-filter04: runTheme === 'Minimalist',
  bohemian-filter04: runTheme === 'Bohemian',
  forest-filter04: runTheme === 'Forest',
  beach-filter04: runTheme === 'Beach',
  sea-filter04: runTheme === 'Sea',
  spring-filter04: runTheme === 'Spring',
  winter-filter04: runTheme === 'Winter',
  summer-filter04: runTheme === 'Summer',
  autumn-filter04: runTheme === 'Autumn'
]
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can create a [directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a directive like this:

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyDirective]',
})
export class MyDirectiveDirective implements OnInit {
  filterclass = '';
  runTheme = 'Green';
  @HostBinding('class') filterClass = 'blue-filter04';
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    switch (this.runTheme) {
      case 'Blue':
        this.filterClass = 'blue-filter04';
        break;
      case 'Green':
        this.filterClass = 'green-filter04';
        break;
      case 'Red':
        this.filterClass = 'red-filter04';
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

this is an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hxh1w1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-directive.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks Mojtaba for your advice! I have tried and it works well in your code. But when i try to bring in a service into the directive, it does not seem to be working anymore. Please take a look at my example with your codes. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kcm5rf?file=src/app/my-directive.directive.ts

Comment: When buttons are clicked, the runTheme value successfully sends to the directive created. But the filter classes are not applying on the image?

Comment: sorry for my late.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ud5r8r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-directive.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbuttons%2Fcolor-schemes.service.ts

Comment: It's working flawlessly now. Thank you so much. Learnt something new today :)